# Android kotlin coroutines return object from lifecycle scopes

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a function `getNewProduct` that it should be return an object of type `ProductCats`. Inside this function I call a `Async` method and cause of it I should call it by coroutine scopes. this is codes:

```
    private fun addProductCatAsync(pc: ProductCats) = viewModelScope.async {
        withContext(Dispatchers.Default){
            productService.addProductCatToServer(pc)
        }
    }

    fun getNewProduct(pc: ProductCats) = viewModelScope.launch{

        if (_newProduct.value == null) {
            val res = addProductCatAsync(pc).await()
            _newProduct.value = res
            println("NEW PRODUCT INSIDE COROUTINE: ${_newProduct.value}")
            return@launch res
        }
        return@launch _newProduct.value
    }
```

but i got this error on compile time, from lines of return: `required: Unit, found: ProductCats?`. How can I convert `getNewProduct` function and make it return my desired object instead ob `job`?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
fun getNewProduct(pc: ProductCats): ProductCats{
    label@GlobalScope.launch{
        if (_newProduct.value == null) {
        val res = addProductCatAsync(pc).await()
        _newProduct.value = res
        println("NEW PRODUCT INSIDE COROUTINE: ${_newProduct.value}")
        return@label res
    }
    return _newProduct.value
}



GlobalScope.launch will return job object.
```

Comment: This launches a job and then returns the value that `_newProduct` has before the job starts.

Answer (score 0):

If you want take result, you can use async instead launch

```
fun getNewProduct(pc: ProductCats) = viewModelScope.async {
if (_newProduct.value == null) {
    val res = addProductCatAsync(pc).await()
    _newProduct.value = res
    println("NEW PRODUCT INSIDE COROUTINE: ${_newProduct.value}")
}
_newProduct.value
}.await()
```

Comment: This won’t work unless the function is a suspend function.